# How do I add a filter on a product attribute to Magento Advanced Export Profiles?

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

I want to filter my data to csv using the "Manufacturer" field.  I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
<action type="catalog/convert_adapter_product" method="load">
    <var name="store"><![CDATA[0]]></var>
    <var name="filter/manufacturer"><![CDATA[898]]></var>
</action>

<action type="catalog/convert_parser_product" method="unparse">
    <var name="store"><![CDATA[0]]></var>
    <var name="url_field"><![CDATA[0]]></var>
</action>

<action type="dataflow/convert_mapper_column" method="map">
    <var name="map">
        <map name="sku"><![CDATA[sku]]></map>
        <map name="name"><![CDATA[name]]></map>
    </var>
    <var name="_only_specified">true</var>
</action>

<action type="dataflow/convert_parser_csv" method="unparse">
    <var name="delimiter"><![CDATA[,]]></var>
    <var name="enclose"><![CDATA["]]></var>
    <var name="fieldnames">true</var>
</action>

<action type="dataflow/convert_adapter_io" method="save">
    <var name="type">file</var>
    <var name="path">var/export</var>
    <var name="filename"><![CDATA[safety-gates-export.csv]]></var>
</action>
```

Any thoughts on how to get this to work with filtering on other attributes than the default ones?

Comment: Do you know How can i export category name not category id by data flow profiles export,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, from reading the code it looks like the set of attributes you can filter on is very limited.

```
$attrFilterArray = array();
$attrFilterArray ['name']           = 'like';
$attrFilterArray ['sku']            = 'startsWith';
$attrFilterArray ['type']           = 'eq';
$attrFilterArray ['attribute_set']  = 'eq';
$attrFilterArray ['visibility']     = 'eq';
$attrFilterArray ['status']         = 'eq';
$attrFilterArray ['price']          = 'fromTo';
$attrFilterArray ['qty']            = 'fromTo';
$attrFilterArray ['store_id']       = 'eq';
```

To filter on other attributes requires a minor extension to the class.

**/app/code/local/YourCompany/YourModule/Model/DataFlow/Catalog/Product/Adapter.php**

```
<?php
class YourCompany_YourModule_Model_DataFlow_Catalog_Product_Adapter 
extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Convert_Adapter_Product
{

    /**
     * Extend the parent method to add filtering capability for additional fields
     *
     * This is required since the parent load() uses a parent::setFilter instead of $this->setFilter
     *
     * @return Mage_Dataflow_Model_Convert_Adapter_Interface
     */
    public function load()
    {
        // Add any additional attributes you want to filter on here
        $attrFilterArray = array(
            'manufacturer' => 'eq',
        );

        $this->setFilter($attrFilterArray, array());

        return parent::load();
    }

}
```

**/app/code/local/YourCompany/YourModule/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <YourCompany_YourModule>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </YourCompany_YourModule>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <convert_adapter_product>YourCompany_YourModule_Model_DataFlow_Catalog_Product_Adapter</convert_adapter_product>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

Comment: sorry for the late reply.. I hope you get the bounty I put on this one.. great solution.

Comment: Well, seeing that the question is tagged "magento-1.4" I wouldn't expect it to work for 1.7 without some modification.

Answer (score 0):

I know this topic is old but this may help someone - works in Magento 1.9. This would be better as a Module but this is a "quick fix".  Back up all files before uploading. I needed to add Product ID (from > to) and Manufacturer dropdown field but can easily be adopted for most attribute types.

FOR System > Import/Export > DataProfiles > Export All Products

app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Convert/Adapter/Product.php
**copy to**
app/code/**local**/Mage/Catalog/Model/Convert/Adapter/Product.php

**FIND** public function load()
Add Attributes to  $attrFilterArray = array();

```
$attrFilterArray = array();
$attrFilterArray ['name']           = 'like';
$attrFilterArray ['entity_id']      = 'fromTo'; //Custom Field
$attrFilterArray ['manufacturer']   = 'eq';     //Custom Field
$attrFilterArray ['sku']            = 'startsWith';
$attrFilterArray ['type']           = 'eq';
$attrFilterArray ['attribute_set']  = 'eq';
$attrFilterArray ['visibility']     = 'eq';
$attrFilterArray ['status']         = 'eq';
$attrFilterArray ['price']          = 'fromTo';
$attrFilterArray ['qty']            = 'fromTo';
$attrFilterArray ['store_id']       = 'eq';
```

If type ="**fromTo**" you need to add an extra filter before **return parent::load();**
The following is for entity_id

```
if ($productId = $this->getFieldValue($filters, 'entity_id')) {
    $this->_filter[] = array(
    'attribute' => 'entity_id',
    'from'      => $productId['from'],
    'to'        => $productId['to']
    );  

    $this->setJoinAttr(array(
    'alias'     => 'entity_id',
    'attribute' => 'catalog_product/entity_id',
    'bind'      => 'entity_id',
    'joinType'  => 'LEFT'
    ));
}
```

Add the fields to the form

app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/system/convert/profile/wizard.phtml
**Duplicate as a Backup**

**Find**

```
<div class="profile_entity_type_product">
```

Add extra Field Sets within this div

The following is for the **fromTo** for entity id

```
<span class="field-row">
    <label for="product_filter_entity_id_from"><?php echo $this->__("Product ID:") ?></label>
    <input class="input-text" style="width:5em" id="product_filter_entity_id_from" name="gui_data[product][filter][entity_id][from]" value="<?php echo $this->getValue('gui_data/product/filter/entity_id/from') ?>"/> <?php echo $this->__('to') ?>
    <input class="input-text" style="width:5em" id="product_filter_entity_id_to" name="gui_data[product][filter][entity_id][to]" value="<?php echo $this->getValue('gui_data/product/filter/entity_id/to') ?>"/>
</span>
```

The following is for the Manufacturer dropdown

```
<span class="field-row">
<label for="product_filter_manufacturer"><?php echo $this->__("Manufacturer Name:") ?></label><select id="product_filter_manufacturer" name="gui_data[product][filter][manufacturer]">
    <?php $manufacturer = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product','manufacturer')->getSource()->getAllOptions(); ?>
    <?php foreach ($manufacturer as $option): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $option['value'] ?>" <?php echo $this->getSelected('gui_data/product/filter/manufacturer', $option['value']) ?>><?php echo htmlspecialchars($option['label']) ?></option>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</select>
```