# Adding category filter to Magento 1.9 product export

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, export-to-csv

I'm trying to add functionality to Magento's standard export filter, namely the possibility to export my products filtered by category. Can this be done without needing an extension. My searches on this topic only revealed answers for Magento 1.4. And off course a bucket load of extensions, but I really would like to extend only this core functionality. Any help in this area would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Whenever you override core functionality you in essence create an extension (if done correctly), so you're always going to need an extension, whether it's custom or not is a different matter. What have you actually tried so far, apart from just searching and asking for code?

Comment: At the moment I'm trying to modify an answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7194756 to get it to work in 1.9. It seemed to me this could be a really common problem for a lot of people, so I was hoping someone already had a solution to this problem. If/When I get this working in 1.9 I will post the solution. Until then, if someone has already tried this, I would appreciate their feedback/solution.